# More convert jquery object to string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Yes I have see the post [here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-get-full-html-string-including.html)

And I tried that but the problem is, my jquery object looks more like this:

```
var $foo = $('<ul><li id="' + line.id + '" label="' + label + '" rel="file"><a href="#">' + line.title + '</a></li></ul>');
$foo.click(function() { openLink(line.url) });
$foo.appendTo($myDiv);
```

When $myDiv is fully populated I can do this:

```
var html = $('<div>').append($('#foo').clone()).remove().html();
```

And I will see all of the lovely HTML, but I don't know if the click stuff will be preserved. See, I want to save the entire DOM modification to localStorage so I can retrieve it quickly since it's pretty static. I need to be able to store it and all its attributes, then yank it back out and restore it, clicks and all.

Does that make sense?

Comment: You cannot save a function as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do this would be to use inline event handlers, which is a bad (and slow) idea.

Instead, you can convert all of your event handlers to `live` handlers; they will then automatically apply to all matching elements without having to rebind them after changing the DOM.

Comment: I agree. You could identify which to bind with a class name, and store your line.url in an attribute directly on the UL or whatever you want to be clicked.

Comment: Definitely the way to go here. Check out **[the official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** for implementation details.

Comment: Oh nice. So instead of "$foo.click(function() { openLink(line.url) });" I would implement a more dynamic "live" handler? I will try that! Awesome, thanks!

Comment: One quick question, how would I go about saving line.url as an attribute directly on the URL and accessing it in my .live handler?

Comment: @user: `$(this).getAttr("url")`